# How dynamically increase or decrease the number of split view's of a view controller in Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have try to find out programatically add the number of split's of a view controller as per our requirement based upon situation. For example initially we have set a 3 split's view to the view controller page and after some operations we want increase the another split in that view controller. As like that we can able to modify the number of split's count dynamically is my requirement. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`NSSplitViewController` has three methods for manipulating with the `NSSplitViewItem` array.

- AddSplitViewItem
- RemoveSplitViewItem
- InsertSplitViewItem

Example:

```
MySplitViewController = new MySplitViewController(); // a NSSplitViewController subclass
var splitViewItem = new NSSplitViewItem();
splitViewItem.ViewController = new RandomViewControllerController();
MySplitViewController.AddSplitViewItem(splitViewItem);
var splitViewItem2 = new NSSplitViewItem();
splitViewItem2.ViewController = new RandomViewControllerController();
MySplitViewController.AddSplitViewItem(splitViewItem2);
PresentViewControllerAsModalWindow(MySplitViewController);
```

Re: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssplitviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for response, My scenario is In story board I am creating one view controller, In that view controller I am adding split view controller, It has two splits. Then how can I increase that split's count dynamically.

Comment: @Deepak Call `AddSplitViewItem` on your split view controller with a new `NSSplitViewItem` that is assigned the additional ViewController that you wish to show...

Comment: Sorry SushilHangover, Actually I am using 'NSSplitView' In my view controller. In that there is no option for adding split view item.

Comment: @Deepak `NSSplitView` has an `AddSubview`, create your `NSView` subclass and call AddSubView with it...

Comment: Thanks Shshil, It works great. I have one doubt i.e It will adjust the width of the split view If I added view controller is increased But I want to set each split width with minimum width. How can I get that.

Comment: @Deepak NSSplitView allows you to set the "Holding" priority of each view to allow it to maintain its width or height in regards to the other views ( `SetHoldingPriority`) Assuming you are using AutoLayout with the view that you are adding so those views can have an implicit width or an width constraint that is equal to or greater then some constant.

Comment: Hi Shasil, I have tried what you have said, It works great but when content size is exceed the screen size horizontal scrolling is not worked. How can I get it.